# using unicode characters with wxPython

Tags: python, unicode, wxpython, character

i have a problem with wxpython and his rich text control, when I try to insert unicode characters... \xb2 prints an apex '2', '\u2074' should print an apex '4'...
edit: I use windows vista... and I tried 'coding cp1252 ' and 'utf-8' but with the same result...
2edit:
on vista it crashs, on xp it shows a strange square (i guess it's when the pc doesn't recognize the character...)

here is the source code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import wx
import wx.richtext as rt

class Trial(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Prova', 
                size=(400, 400))

        self.rtc = rt.RichTextCtrl(self, style=wx.VSCROLL|wx.HSCROLL|wx.NO_BORDER)
        wx.CallAfter(self.rtc.SetFocus)
        #self.rtc.Freeze()
        self.rtc.BeginFontSize(14)
        self.rtc.WriteText('hei!\xb2') #alright
        self.rtc.WriteText('hi\u2074!')#crash
        self.rtc.EndFontSize()
        
       
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = Trial()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

but when I try to run it, it crashs...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    frame = display.Trial()
  File "C:\Users\expert\Desktop\display.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.rtc.WriteText('hi\u2074!')
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-ansi\wx\richtext.py", line 2507, in WriteText
    return _richtext.RichTextCtrl_WriteText(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2074' in position 4: character maps to <undefined>
```

so...what should I do? I really need to show it...

thanks everybody!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want Unicode support then you should be using the unicode version of wxpython.

> There are two versions of wxPython for
>   each of the supported Python versions
>   on Win32. They are nearly identical,
>   except one of them has been compiled
>   with support for the Unicode version
>   of the platform APIs. Unless you've
>   been told differently, you probably
>   want to get the Unicode build of
>   wxPython.

Most other platforms also have two versions.

It works fine if you pass the actual symbols e.g

```
self.rtc.WriteText("hei!²")
```

Comment: nothing...i re-installed wxpython 2.6 (unicode version) but it present exactly the same output... (i already had that version, but i didn't remember...)

Comment: Your right I just tested... Im not sure why that is but it works fine if use the actual symbols instead of the utf representation i.e `self.rtc.WriteText("hei!²")` works.

Comment: @ant: The installation path contains "wx-2.8-msw-ansi" so I'm sure you *didn't* have the Unicode version. Make sure you uninstall the wxPython package completely and reinstall the Unicode build. More infos on http://wiki.wxpython.org/UnicodeBuild

Comment: Actually `'\xb2'` works but `'\u2074'` is shown as a square box.

Comment: It's shown as square box because your font doesn't contain that glyph. U+2074 is "superscript 4" and not contained in many fonts, whereas ² is in most fonts. Try another non-Windows-1252 character such as U+04B0 (should work with Tahoma).

Comment: @andi but i've installed the unicode version...from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.8.11.0/wxPython2.8-win32-unicode-2.8.11.0-py26.exe/download and also i checked that the installation would become the standard one... indeed, "unicode" in wx.PlatformInfo returns True

Comment: @volting yeah, like to me ... @andi sorry i'm not sure i understood what you've written...

Comment: @ant: So now that you installed the Unicode version and get the same behavior as volting (square box instead of character), your problem is solved. Choose a system font like "DejaVu Sans" that supports the "superscript four" glyph in order to see the character.

Comment: @AndiDog: +1 I hadn't even thought of font support, Ill have to remember this for the next time I have unicode issues.

Comment: i cant' make +1 cause i haven't enough reputation...i'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes occur if you forget to set your encoding. Put this at the top of the code:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
```

before any code including comments but after the shebang (#!/usr/bin/python)

Comment: Wrong, forgetting the encoding line will lead to a `SyntaxError` instead of `UnicodeEncodeError`.