# Displaying unicode characters in Windows wxpython just shows box

Tags: python, unicode, wxpython

I want to display an arrow up, arrow down, and eject icons on buttons in wxpython. In osx these all display fine, but on Windows 7 these just display as a small box.
Anyway to get these to display correctly in Windows?

```
self.buttonClear = wx.Button(self, -1, u"\u23CF", pos=(28,510), size=(40,-1))
self.buttonClear.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.clearList)

self.buttonmoveUp = wx.Button(self, -1, u"\u2B06", pos=(78,510), size=(40,-1))
self.buttonmoveUp.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.moveUp)

self.buttonmoveDown = wx.Button(self, -1, u"\u2B07", pos=(118,510), size=(40,-1))
self.buttonmoveDown.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.moveDown)
```

Comment: Do you have a font installed that has those glyphs?

Comment: First of all, Unix and Windows uses system default encodings, a character definition in Unix will there for be different in Windows unless you specify the character-encoding within your application, otherwise you'll default to the system default. Also instead of doing `u"\23CF"` try writing the character "as is", for instance `\x246` would be `ö`, i'd simply write out the letter as it is.

Comment: Also you need the unicode build of wxPython, otherwise this will occur, see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849817/using-unicode-characters-with-wxpython

Comment: I'm using this version wxPython3.0-win32-3.0.0.0-py27 ios there a link to the unicode version?

Comment: Starting with 2.9 there is no separate ansi/unicode builds any more.  They are all equivallent to the old unicode build.

Comment: Thats good, I just ended up using other unicode characters, but Robin why do the ones above not work in Windows?

Comment: What @Ignacio said. Windows doesn't ship with a font that supports those characters. Suggest using an image instead.